# CompletableFuture simplified custom example

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

Could someone explain the original source of CompletableFuture in simple ways? Particularly what happens in timedGet(long nanos)? This is source code link https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java

How CompletableFuture watches an execution of a thread and times out?

Comment: That is a line majority restrict themselves into. Certain things demand to cross that line and check out things for many other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I won't take upon myself to explain the entire CompletableFuture, as it's about 2K lines long, but I cad definitely explain `timedGet()`

Note that we're discussing OpenJDK here, OracleJDK is a bit different.

There are some checks before the meaty part and some cleanups after. I'll leave them.

```
long d = System.nanoTime() + nanos;
// Arguments are interruptible, nanos, deadline
Signaller q = new Signaller(true, nanos, d == 0L ? 1L : d); // avoid 0
boolean queued = false;

// We wait until we get the result
// If it's already there, we simply return it
while ((r = result) == null) {
    // So, the result is not there
    // If it's the first time we run this loop, or we didn't manage to push signaller on the stacked queued=false 
    if (!queued)
         queued = tryPushStack(q);
    // Something interrupted us. It could be either thread interrupt or timeout
    else if (q.interruptControl < 0 || q.nanos <= 0L) {
        q.thread = null;
        cleanStack();
        if (q.interruptControl < 0)
            return null;
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }
    else if (q.thread != null && result == null) {
       try {
          // Waits for q, without blocking the thread
          ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(q);
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           q.interruptControl = -1;
       }
   }
}
```